# Can I define my own "if any" syntax in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I constantly write something like:

```
val if val && !val.empty?
```

Can I define this syntax more concisely to something like:

```
val if_any
```

or

```
val if any
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variation of the Object method that returns the actual value.

```
class Object
  def if_any?
    self if self && (!self.respond_to?(:empty?) || !self.empty?)
  end
end

[].if_any? # => nil
[42].if_any? # => [42]

"".if_any? # => nil
"hi".if_any? # => "hi"

# and for the objects that don't define #empty?
nil.if_any? # => nil
42.if_any? # => 42
false.if_any? # => nil
true.if_any? # => true
```

Edit: Hmm, after looking at this again, I think I wouldn't use a question mark in the method name, as it goes against ruby convention of returning boolean.

Answer (score 4):

There is val.blank?

```
irb(main):008:0> ''.blank?
=> true
irb(main):009:0> '   '.blank?
=> true
irb(main):010:0> nil.blank?
=> true
irb(main):011:0> false.blank?
=> true
irb(main):012:0> 'whatever'.blank?
=> false
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. But I want to explore the metaprogramming flexibility of ruby to define self-customized syntax. I kind of expect some solution like LISP's macro way.

Comment: BTW, it is kinda surprising false.blank? returns true.

Comment: either false, nil or empty string/array (or white space array).

Comment: blank? is a rails method, btw

Comment: Ohh Yeah. blank? is an alias of empty? The code for empty? in rails are: def empty? ; all? { |k, v| v && v.empty? }; end

Answer (score 2):

No, I don’t believe Ruby allows you to extend the syntax that way. The closest you could get is adding a method to Object:

```
class Object
  def any?
    !!self && !self.empty?
  end
end

"hi".any? # => true
[].any?   # => false
nil.any?  # => false

if x.any?
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Haven't really done it, but why not change active record base ? I'm pretty certain that it is easily doable.

Comment: I think you should define it for `String`, `Array` and other classes were `empty?` is defined as it will give error `NoMethod error empty?` for those objects...for example, `1.any?` gives `NoMethod Error empty?`..if it was no method `any?` it was ok...Not a big thing but just noticed..

Comment: I believe the objective is to return the value if it's not empty, not true or false.